# Chroot Ignoring systemctl Request in ubuntu

Tags: sql-server, ubuntu, chroot

I am trying to install Microsoft SQL Server on my Ubuntu 16.04.4 OS. 
I have successfully installed the program and now I am trying to configure the installation.

```
sudo /opt/mssql/bin/mssql-conf setup
```

The response is:

`An instance of SQL Server is running. Please stop the SQL Server service using the following command`:

`sudo systemctl stop mssql-server`

After running this command, the response is

`Running in chroot, ignoring request`

So my problem is that I cannot get out of chroot in order to stop SQL service.

Can anyone advise? Let me know if you need more information.

Comment: Hello and welcome on SO :) If you want people here to help you, maybe you could [make it easier for them](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to understand your problem, for instance by providing a little more context (what are you trying to achieve, where have you looked for documentation) and by formatting your post with [markdown](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting).

Answer (score 0):

He is probably trying to do unattended installation (chroot/in-target during distro installation). Intended result is that target machine has *mssql-server* service installed and running after distro installation.

I am having exactly same issue, but have not found the way to fix this.
Tried:

```
service mssql-server stop --skip-redirect
```

but did not work: "unrecognized service"